# write clean url's in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

i want to write my urls with this format of string :
http://www.mysite.com/news/2012/10/04/article-title
but when i use RewriteRule in htaccess file site styles dont work correctly . i have this question : what is the best way to do this in php ?
formerly i do this in asp.net whit rewrite module , but now i can't do this, i've searched so many times and read many articles , but still have this problem ....
thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a single point of entry:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=$1 [L]
```

This way, all requests will be routed to the index page, with a GET variable containing the wanted address. Now, you can decide how to route (with includes) inside of PHP, where control is easier.

Also, you should be using absolute paths to point to your styles, or have a PHP variable to include the absolute paths of your styles.

The above `.htaccess` makes sure that if the file exists, it won't rewrite the URL. (lines 2-3).

Comment: when i use this htaccess codes , first my styles works fine , but when i go to the other url's like : www.mysite.com/test/ my styles gone , i cheked css paths , in this case i changed the css path to : href="../css/main.css" and my styles work corectly !

Comment: how define a variable to fix my css and js paths?

Comment: i solved the problem using this codes :define('ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));
 define('ROOT_URL', substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 0, - (strlen($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) - strlen(ROOT_DIR))));

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I use absolute URLs (or at least relative to the root) when putting in my stylesheets and scripts:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />
```

If that doesn't work for you, then you are probably rewriting your CSS paths as well. Exclude files as needed (probably best done by checking if it ends with certain extensions)

Comment: Good points - relative to root helps a lot. I usually keep styles/JS files/images in a "data" folder which I exclude from any rewriting. Seems easier than excluding certain extensions, since you can then put whatever you don't want rewritten (including PHP and HTML) in the data folder.

Comment: ho can i do this ? for example i can do keep my css , js , img files into the extra folder and exclude that folder from rewriting , but how?

Answer (score 0):

If your rules are set up correctly but your CSS formatting is gone after that, it means the relative path to your CSS file is now incorrect.

You're probably using something like this right now:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
```

Change it to this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css" />
```

Comment: i changed css file path but it dosent work

Answer (score 0):

The solution I use is the base html tag, sorts out images and style sheets.

be sure to use: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` at least - maybe make that more secure, so direct paths still work as well.

Comment: i have this line in my htaccess file , but still have the problem \